# Why can't I change vim syntax highlighting via local vimrc file?

Tags: vim, syntax, highlighting

I am trying to customize vim highlighting by placing additional instructions into local config `$project/.lvimrc`, which is managed by the https://github.com/embear/vim-localvimrc plugin.

Unfortunately, it seems that commands like

```
syntax match Operator "\<MYOP\>"
```

located in `.lvimrc` are ignored silently by vim. Typing the command in the command line works as expected. Other commands from `.lvimrc` also work. So what may stop vim from interpreting local highlighting correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was because https://github.com/embear/vim-localvimrc plugin launches local files in a sandbox by default. Syntax commands are not allowed in a sandbox (at least in my setup), so the exception was raised. For some reason, Vim handles such exceptions silently.

In my case, the following modifications formed a solution:

1. Disable sandboxes for localvimrc by adding `let g:localvimrc_sandbox = 0` to master .vimrc file
2. Add `set conceallevel=2` to the localvimrc

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem with the loading order, i.e., your `.lvimrc` is loaded, then the filetype syntax is loaded and overwrites the `.lvimrc` syntax commands. You could check that by including `echom` statements on both files.

Also notice that the local vimrc is not the standard way of customizing syntax highlight. From [Vim FAQ 24.11](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-24.11):

```
You should not modify the syntax files supplied with Vim to add your
extensions. When you install the next version of Vim, you will lose your
changes. Instead you should create a file under the ~/.vim/after/syntax
directory with the same name as the original syntax file and add your
additions to this file.

For more information, read 

    |mysyntaxfile-add|
    |'runtimepath'|
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found a better mechanism for debugging this kind of issues: the -V command line option. For example, running Vim with `vim -V13trace file_to_edit` records the call trace to the `trace` file with the verbose level 13